# Can someone help me with a charge of SelectOneMenu from database?

Tags: java, jsf

Can anyone help me with creating a convert to evaluate the data of a SelectOneMenu and return the one that matches?

I currently have one, but when I run my application it throws me the following error: "Conversion Error setting value '1' for 'null Converter'."

I have added a control with System.out.println () to show what the renderer is processing, but it is not even entering the convert class.

My class is as follows:

```
@FacesConverter("conversorMovil")

public class ConversorMovil implements Converter {

    private Session sesion;
    private Transaction transaccion;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value){



        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                this.sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                this.transaccion = sesion.beginTransaction();

                DaoMovil daoM = new DaoMovil();
                //Moviles movil = (Moviles) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("mbMovil");
                Moviles movil=null;
                try {
                    movil = daoM.buscarPorCodigo(this.sesion, Integer.parseInt(value));
                    this.transaccion.commit();
                } catch (Exception ex) {     
          Logger.getLogger(ConversorMovil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                System.out.println("Valor devuelto por getAsObject()" + movil.toString());
                return movil;       
            }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid theme."));
            }finally{
                this.sesion.close();
            }
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if(object != null) {
            System.out.println("Valor devuelto por getAsString()" + String.valueOf(((Moviles) object).getIdmovil()));
            return String.valueOf(((Moviles) object).getIdmovil());
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

This converter should return the data of vehicles loaded in a database.

My xhtml is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

<body>

    <ui:composition template="./../plantilla/plantilla.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="frmNuevoVale">
                <p:commandButton value="Nuevo Vale" onclick="PF('dialogoNuevoVale').show();"/>
            </h:form>

            <h2>Lista de Vales</h2>

            <h:form id="frmListaVales">
                <p:growl id="mensajeGeneral" showDetail="true" sticky="false"/>

                <p:dataTable id="tablaVales" var="fila" value="#{mbVale.todos}" paginator="true" rows="10" selection="#{mbVale.vale}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{fila.idvale}">

                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":frmListaVales:detalleVale" oncomplete="PF('dialogoVale').show();"/>

                    <f:facet name="cabecera">
                        Lista de Vales
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="Número de Vale:">
                        <h:outputText value="#{fila.idvale}" style="float:right"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Fecha Emisión">
                        <h:outputText value="#{fila.fechaemision}" style="float:right"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Guardia">
                        <h:outputText value="#{fila.guardias.idguardia}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Anulado">
                        <!-- <h:outputText value="#{fila.baja}"/> -->
                        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/iconos/aceptar.ico" rendered="#{fila.anulado == true}" style="center"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Fecha de Baja">
                        <h:outputText value="#{fila.fechaanulacion}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton value="Editar" actionListener="#{mbVale.buscarValeEditar(fila.idvale)}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton value="Dar de Baja" actionListener="#{mbVale.buscarValeBaja(fila.idvale)}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>

                <p:dialog header="Detalle de Vale" widgetVar="dialogoVale" resizable="false" width="300" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">
                    <p:panelGrid id="detalleVale" columns="2">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Número de Vale:"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{mbVale.vale.idvale}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Fecha de Emisión:"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{mbVale.vale.fechaemision}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Emisor:"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{mbVale.vale.guardias.idguardia}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Anulado:"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{mbVale.vale.anulado}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Fecha de Baja:"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{mbVale.vale.fechaanulacion}"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>                    
            </h:form>

            <h:form id="frmAltaVale">
                <p:dialog header="Nuevo Vale" widgetVar="dialogoNuevoVale" resizable="false" width="900" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" >
                    <p:panelGrid id="nuevoVale" columns="3">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Número de Vale:" for="txtIdentificador"/>
                        <p:outputLabel id="txtIdentificador" value="#{mbVale.vale.idvale}">
                            <!--<f:validator validatorId="validadorVacio"/>-->
                        </p:outputLabel>
                        <p:message for="txtIdentificador"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="txtMovil" value="Móvil:"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="txtMovil" value="#{mbVale.vale.moviles}" style="width:175px" converter="#{conversorMovil}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{mbMovil.todos}" var="mov" itemValue ="#{mov.idmovil}" itemLabel = "#{mov.descripcion}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:message for="txtMovil"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="txtChofer" value="Chofer:" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="txtChofer" value="#{mbChofer.chofer.idchofer}" style="width:175px">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{mbChofer.todos}" var="chof" itemValue ="#{chof.idchofer}" itemLabel = "#{chof.nombre}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:message for="txtChofer"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="txtCombustible" value="Combustible:" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="txtCombustible" value="#{mbCombustible.combustible.idcombustible}" style="width:175px">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{mbCombustible.todos}" var="comb" itemValue ="#{comb.idcombustible}" itemLabel = "#{comb.descripcion}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:message for="txtCombustible"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="txtProveedor" value="Proveedor:" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="txtProveedor" value="#{mbProveedor.proveedor.idproveedor}" style="width:175px">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{mbProveedor.todos}" var="prov" itemValue ="#{prov.idproveedor}" itemLabel = "#{prov.descripcion}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:message for="txtProveedor"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Kilómetros:" for="txtKilometros"/>
                        <p:inputText id="txtKilometros" label="Nombre" value="#{mbVale.vale.kilometros}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="validadorVacio"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="txtKilometros"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Litros:" for="txtLitros"/>
                        <p:inputText id="txtLitros" label="Nombre" value="#{mbVale.vale.litros}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="validadorVacio"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="txtLitros"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Registrar Vale" actionListener="#{mbVale.registrar()}" update="nuevoVale,:frmListaVales"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>

            <h:form id="frmEditarVale">
                <p:dialog header="Editar Vale" widgetVar="dialogoEditarVale" modal="true" resizable="false" width="900" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" >
                    <p:panelGrid id="editarVale" columns="3">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Número de Vale:" for="txtIdentificador"/>
                        <p:outputLabel id="txtIdentificador" value="#{mbVale.vale.idvale}"/>    
                        <p:message for="txtIdentificador"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Fecha de Emisión:" for="txtEmision"/>
                        <p:inputText id="txtEmision" label="legajo" value="#{mbVale.vale.fechaemision}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="validadorCero"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="txtEmision"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Kilómetros:" for="txtKilometros"/>
                        <p:inputText id="txtKilometros" label="Nombre" value="#{mbVale.vale.kilometros}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="validadorVacio"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="txtKilometros"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Confirmar Edición" actionListener="#{mbVale.modificarVale()}" update=":frmListaVales,editarVale"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>

            <!-- Formulario para dar de baja choferes -->
            <h:form id="frmBajaVale">

                <p:dialog header="Dar de Baja Vale" widgetVar="dialogoBajaVale" resizable="false" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">

                    <p:panelGrid id="bajaVale" columns="3">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Número de Vale:" for="txtIdentificador"/>
                        <p:outputLabel id="txtIdentificador"  value="#{mbVale.vale.idvale}"/>
                        <p:message for="txtIdentificador"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Emisión:" for="txtEmision"/>
                        <p:outputLabel id="txtEmision"  value="#{mbVale.vale.fechaemision}"/>
                        <p:message for="txtEmision"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Kilómetros:" for="txtKilometros"/>
                        <p:outputLabel id="txtKilometros" value="#{mbVale.vale.kilometros}"/>
                        <p:message for="txtKilometros"/>
                        <h:panelGroup/>
                        <h:outputText value="¿Realmente desea dar de baja a este registro? "/>
                        <h:panelGroup/>

                        <p:commandButton value="Si" icon="ui-icon-borrar" actionListener="#{mbVale.bajaVale()}" update=":frmListaVales,bajaVale"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="No" icon="ui-icon-cancelar" oncomplete="PF('dialogoBajaVale').hide();"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>

                </p:dialog>

            </h:form>

        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="bottom">
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
```

The point I am using it is in "frmAltaVales".

I want to select a vehicle (movil), and pass its Id to the Vouchers class.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: @JasperdeVries sorry, i have translated

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to pass the id of the converter, not the converter as a bean:
Don't use:

```
converter="#{conversorMovil}"
```

Use

```
converter="conversorMovil"
```

Comment: True, I do not know what I was thinking when I inserted it as a Managed Bean in xhtml.

But now I cast a casting error on the getAsString method:
Java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String can not be cast to Pojos.Moviles